# Express JS:- Condition to wait for 50 seconds of firestore query response else continue the other process

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to design simple application which will wait for 50 seconds for an api or db call, if not able to a get response in 50 seconds then discard the call and move to another call!.

```
async (collection, docId, sentences) => {
 let collectionRef = firestore.collection(collection);
 let doc = await collectionRef.doc(docId).get(); // make this wait for 50 secs else discard it.
 cosole.log("After time out");
 ...
```

Thanks for your time in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.race` wraping your original promise and a timeout promise:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const timeout = async (ms) => {
    await wait(ms)
    throw new Error("Timeout after " + ms + " ms");
}

async (collection, docId, sentences) => {
 let collectionRef = firestore.collection(collection);
 let doc
 try {
    doc = await Promise.race([collectionRef.doc(docId).get(), timeout(50*1000)]) // make this wait for 50 secs else discard it.
 } catch (error) {
     // Timeout or other error occurred
 }
 ...
}
```